# Why the promise that I get after reading a value once never is resolved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know why the promise that I get after reading a value once never is resolved. I know this because the then() method never is executed.The program goes from "Publish button have been pressed." to "I am out!".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header").load("header_organization.html", function(){

    console.log("Header loaded.");

    // Set up UI elements
    var publish_button = document.querySelector("#publish_button"),
        logout_button = document.querySelector("#logout_button"),
        title = document.querySelector("#title"),
        date = document.querySelector("#date"),
        hour = document.querySelector("#hour"),
        place = document.querySelector("#place"),
        brief_description = document.querySelector("#brief_description"),
        detailed_description = document.querySelector("#detailed_description"),
        contact_email = document.querySelector("#contact_email"),
        contact_phone_number = document.querySelector("#contact_phone_number"),
        image_input = document.querySelector("#imageUrl");
    console.log("Inputs referenced.");

    //Logout 
    logout_button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      firebase.auth().signOut();
      console.log("You have been logged out");
      window.location = "index.html";
    });

    //Initialize Firebase
    var auth = firebase.auth(),
        storage = firebase.storage(),
        database = firebase.database();

    console.log("Firebase inizialized.");

    //Publish event
    publish_button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log("Publish button have been pressed.");
      //Read a value of one of the user's attributes
      database.ref("users/"+auth.currentUser.uid).once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot){
        console.log("Never reach this point");
      });
      console.log("I am out!");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do your database security rules allow read of `/users/$uid`?

Comment: Yes! It allows reads!

Comment: If you console.log uid do you get any uid, even  does console.log(snapshot) give you any value?

Comment: Append a catch to `.then(...)` to see any error: `.then(...).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Failed: ' + error);
    });`

Comment: @user7814783, yes, I got the uid value ok.

Comment: @BobSnyder, I just did it. There is no error.

Comment: The promise is always pending.

Comment: Are you confident you have an internet connection?

Comment: Of course! And it log ins correctly to the users account, sign outs, access user.uid, I don't understand why it can't get that value.